# Inaccurate count of weekdays for the month of March

Tags: apex, datetime, date

Is there a reason why counting the days of the month of March is inaccurate?

This is the method in counting the weekdays:

```
public integer GetWeekDays(Datetime startDatetime, Datetime endDatetime)
{
    integer weekDays = 0;

    while(startDatetime <= endDatetime)
    {
        if(startDatetime.format('E') != 'Sat' && startDatetime.format('E') != 'Sun')
            weekDays ++;

        startDatetime = startDatetime.addDays(1);
    }

    return weekDays;    
}
```

This what I did to test this:

```
Date EndDate = date.newInstance(2015, 3, 31);
Date StartDate = Date.newInstance(EndDate.year(), EndDate.month(), 1);

DateTime  startDatetime = DateTime.newInstance(StartDate , Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
DateTime monthEndDate = DateTime.newInstance(EndDate , Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));

integer totalWeekDays = GetWeekDays(startDatetime, monthEndDate);

system.debug(totalWeekDays);
```

The output should be `22` but it gives me `21`, I tested this in different month all of them have the correct number of days except for the month of March. I also tried changing years, same problem. It always has an inaccurate total of weekdays.

Comment: I can't explain the problem, but strongly recommend to you that you make use of the separate `Date` class when doing date calculations to eliminate the problems associated with timezones that occur then `Datetime` is used for date calculations.

Comment: @KeithC We also experienced that problem, before we just used `Date` which give us inaccurate result because of the timezone.